# Change System Date in Windows 7+ via C# windows Service with Domain User

Tags: c#

kindly help me to solve the following problem.

I am trying to change computer Date via C# Windows Service. The following command
this command is working in C# windows application if i run it as RUN AS Administrator. but the service is not changing system date by the following command. my pc is on domain and i run this service as domain service account. also i add service@domain account to system administrator group.

```
string strCmdText = "/c DATE ";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

how could i run **cmd** as run **As Administrator** in C# Service which is already run as domain user.

i tried all the solutions which is provided here but still the problem is remain.

Comment: this command works in windows xp which does not required run as administrator, but in windows 7 it required to run as admninistroator

Comment: The question I marked as duplicate has an answer to run cmd with admin rights. Try that answer.

Comment: it is asking administrator password how could i set password in cmd argument

Comment: This is starting to sound like a new and different question. Perhaps you should create another one?

Answer (score 0):

To run CMD in administrator privilage, you simply have to run an application in administrator privilage.

But better way to call an program from console will be using Process object (not static method), where you have more options, eg. can read output, etc.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "date";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
p.Start();
```

Then to input data to the application you have to use StandardInput field of Process class

```
p.StandardInput.Write(string yourDate);
```

And at the end you can gently wait for application to finish it's job.

```
p.WaitForExit();
```

---

To read data from output you have to use this command:

```
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

You can also read this line by line (if you have to):

```
string[] oLines = output.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Should be p.StandardInput.Write**Line** in this case